# Tools that can be used to debug .NET Assembly Load failures

Tags: load, .net-assembly, fusion-log-viewer

What are some good tools you use to debug a .NET assembly load failure that has native dependencies. I have used fusion logger (FUSLOGVW.exe) and ProcMon but they haven't helped me much. Any other tools that are useful?

Thanks,
Mohammed

Comment: Both tools are entirely sufficient to diagnose any kind of load failure.  Fuslogvw.exe for managed dependencies, ProcMon for native ones.  Nobody ever thought of writing another one when these two get the job done so well.  Afaik.

Comment: Obviously I have been using them incorrectly :). Any pointers on how to use both efficiently?

Comment: I ended up attaching the process to Visual Studio and set it to break on all exceptions. The issue turned out to be a "load from remote sources error". How could I have figured this out from Fusion Logger or Proc Mon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other tool I found that was a bit helpful was [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/). After downloading it, use [this tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2011/02/02/using-dependency-walker.aspx) to help you get started.