# Error while installing PowerTools

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I recently installed the latest PowerTools on Tridion 2011 SP1. After installing my CM gives the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Tridion is not defined

Attaching a screenshot of the error below
[image]

If now I remove the PowerTools, I get an following error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.TDSI18NLib, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Interop.TDSI18NLib, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.LocalizationModule.InitializeCulture(Object sender, EventArgs args) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) Assembly manager loaded from: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under executable C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe --- A detailed error log follows. === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE LOG: DisplayName = Interop.TDSI18NLib, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/web/WebUI/WebRoot/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin Calling assembly : Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54, Version=6.1.0.55920, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b. === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\web.config LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Post-policy reference: Interop.TDSI18NLib, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/webui/f9209e65/566ab287/Interop.TDSI18NLib.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/webui/f9209e65/566ab287/Interop.TDSI18NLib/Interop.TDSI18NLib.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/web/WebUI/WebRoot/bin/Interop.TDSI18NLib.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/web/WebUI/WebRoot/bin/Interop.TDSI18NLib/Interop.TDSI18NLib.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/webui/f9209e65/566ab287/Interop.TDSI18NLib.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/webui/f9209e65/566ab287/Interop.TDSI18NLib/Interop.TDSI18NLib.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/web/WebUI/WebRoot/bin/Interop.TDSI18NLib.EXE. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/web/WebUI/WebRoot/bin/Interop.TDSI18NLib/Interop.TDSI18NLib.EXE.

Updated - Screenshot of the Error

[image]

The error from HTML as suggested by Frank.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b'
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(SignatureStruct& signature, Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Signature..ctor(IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.ValidateParameterMetadata(MethodInfo methodInfo)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescriptions(ContractDescription contractDescription, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, Type contractToGetMethodsFrom, ContractDescription declaringContract, MessageDirection direction)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateContractDescription(ServiceContractAttribute contractAttr, Type contractType, Type serviceType, ContractReflectionInfo& reflectionInfo, Object serviceImplementation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(Type contractType)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WCFServiceClientProxyGenerator.GetClientProxyScript(Type contractType, String path, Boolean debugMode, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ProxyGenerator.GetClientProxyScript(Type type, String path, Boolean debug, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsService.get_Contents()
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsService.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsPageResources.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsControlResources.WriteContents(HttpResponse response)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Common.HttpUtilities.OutputWithHTTPCacheHeaders(ICachedResource resource, Nullable`1 cacheDuration)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Controls.TridionPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Tridion/web/WebUI/WebRoot/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\bin
Calling assembly : Tridion.UGC.Model, Version=6.1.0.205, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.DashboardView.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: In general when you get such an error, there is a problem while loading the JavaScript for the dashboard. And of course when the base JavaScript is not loaded, you'll get errors like "Tridion is not defined". If you click the link "Dashboard_vxxx.aspx:3" it will show you the error that was created on the server when loading that file.

Comment: Updated with screenshot as suggested

Comment: Now if you scroll down in that HTML, you will find the error message. Instead of updating the screenshot, just grab the relevant text from it.

Comment: Adding the error from the HTML.

Comment: Clearly one of the assemblies is either not present or an incompatible version. You can reach out to the PowerTools community on their forum: http://groups.google.com/group/tridion-powertools. Alternatively you can learn how to troubleshoot assembly loading problems yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457472/tools-that-can-be-used-to-debug-net-assembly-load-failures

Answer (score 5):

The power tools are an open source project, and the issue tracker is available at:

http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/issues

If you believe you have discovered a bug (or perhaps two), you can help the project team by reporting the problems there. (For bonus points - download the sources and work on a fix!)

Comment: Sure. Will do that. But how can I revert back to the stable version as I am unable to run the CM after removing the PT

Comment: You could try a repair (From the Content Manager Installer).

Comment: And if the repair doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall - sometimes that's more effective.

Comment: I did try all the options, but nothing seems to work. I still get the same error. Hence I am now stuck.